# Java - MongoDB mapping object keys with dashes (Message-Id) to dots (Message.Id). Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc

I have a strange problem with mapping MongoDB objects in document to Java hash maps.

If I store an object with `HashMap` like this `("Message-Id" => "something")` to some collection and get it from db again, the result object will have `HashMap` with this `("Message.Id" => "something")`.

I using Spring Data MongoDB in Spring Boot application.

**Unit test:**

```
package com.mailor.app.data.mapping.bugs;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria.where;
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query.query;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import com.google.common.collect.Maps;
import com.mailor.app.data.DataConfig;
import com.mailor.app.data.TestDataConfig;
import com.mailor.app.data.constants.HeaderParams;
import com.mailor.app.data.mapping.entity.MessageIdTestEntity;

/**
 * @author jakob
 *
 */
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { DataConfig.class, TestDataConfig.class })
public class MessageIdDotDashTest {

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate template;

    @Test
    public void messageIdDotOrDashTest() {
        //HeaderParams.MESSAGE_ID = Message-Id
        dotOrDashInKeyTest(HeaderParams.MESSAGE_ID);
    }

    @Test
    public void contentTypeDotOrDashTest() {
        dotOrDashInKeyTest("Content-Type");
    }

    @Test
    public void somethingDotOrDashTest() {
        dotOrDashInKeyTest("Something-with-dashes");
    }

    @Test
    public void hashMapSetOnKeyWithDashTest() {
        HashMap<String, String> testMap = Maps.newHashMap();
        testMap.put(HeaderParams.MESSAGE_ID, "something");
        assertEquals("something", testMap.get(HeaderParams.MESSAGE_ID));
    }

    private void dotOrDashInKeyTest(String key) {
        String messageId = "some kind of message id";
        MessageIdTestEntity testEntity = new MessageIdTestEntity();
        testEntity.getHeaders().put(key, messageId);
        template.save(testEntity);

        Optional<MessageIdTestEntity> testEntityFromDB = Optional.ofNullable(template.findOne(query(where("code").is(testEntity.getCode())), MessageIdTestEntity.class));
        assertTrue(testEntityFromDB.isPresent());
        assertNotNull(testEntityFromDB.get().getHeaders().get(key)); // THIS FAILING, header key is Message.Id not Message-Id
        assertEquals(messageId, testEntityFromDB.get().getHeaders().get(key));
    }
}
```

**Test object:**

```
package com.mailor.app.data.mapping.entity;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.UUID;

import com.google.common.collect.Maps;

/**
 * @author jakob
 *
 */
public class MessageIdTestEntity {

    private String code = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    private HashMap<String, String> headers = Maps.newHashMap();

    /**
     * @return the code
     */
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    /**
     * @return the headers
     */
    public HashMap<String, String> getHeaders() {
        return headers;
    }

    /**
     * @param headers
     *            the headers to set
     */
    public void setHeaders(HashMap<String, String> headers) {
        this.headers = headers;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Fixed by using**

```
((MappingMongoConverter)
mongoTemplate.getConverter()).setMapKeyDotReplacement("#dot#");
```

**Explanation**

We are using standart notation for dot replacement in mongo db object keys (dots are forbidden there), which using a dash (-) as replacement for dot (.).

```
((MappingMongoConverter)
mongoTemplate.getConverter()).setMapKeyDotReplacement("-");
```

But, if you have a object key with dash now, MongoDB mapper replace dash with dot, because he dont know whether you saving key with dash or dot previously.
For this reason, we must use unique dot key replacement like #dot# or something rare, something you never use in object key names.